# when I use "execute shell script on remote host using ssh" in jenkins, there is an error, but it still builds successfully. How to fix it?

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins to deploy my project. I created a job that executes shell script on remote host using ssh.

There are my scripts.

```
cd my-project;
git pull;
npm install;
npm test;
pm2 update;
```

When some script is failed, for example

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The commands will be continued to execute and the output of Jenkins is "Finished: SUCCESS".

But I expect it to fail to build.

How do I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins consider script run as successful if it return zero exit code and failed if not. By default, the whole script exit code is the last executed command's one.
 
You may use `set -e` in the beginning of your script to immediately exit if any command ends with non-zero exit code. Or, if you need to execute all commands, set intermediate variable and return its value in the end.